# How to display not id but another value in ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my code for the hotel website

```
models.py
```

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Комната', unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория', related_name='wer')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Статус', default=True)
    price = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Цена', null=True,blank=True)


class Registrations(models.Model):
    room_num = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Номер', related_name='ertgdb',
                                 limit_choices_to={'room_bool': True})
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    tel_num = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    img = models.FileField(verbose_name='Паспорт', null=True, blank=True)
    visit_date = models.DateField(default=now, verbose_name='Дата прибытия')
    leave_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Дата отбытия')
    guest_count = models.IntegerField(default=1, verbose_name='Кол-во людей')
    room_relevant = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Статус')
    price = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Цена', default=100)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class RegistrationSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Registrations
        fields = ('id', 'room_num', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'tel_num', 'img',
                  'visit_date', 'guest_count', 'room_relevant')
```

[image: q]

I need the room_num field (in the picture) to have not Id but room_num as in the Input form

SlugRelatedField doesn't work because I can't make POST PUT requests later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
class RegistrationSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room = serializers.CharField(source="room_num.room")
    
    class Meta:
        model = Registrations
        fields = ('id', 'room', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'tel_num', 'img',
                  'visit_date', 'guest_count', 'room_relevant')
```

Comment: but then the choice of available rooms disappears with the help of choice

Comment: Don't you want to have both ? @QadyrIsrafilov